# Como alterar a cor de uma nova tela no aplicativo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-xml

Meu aplicativo tem cores definidas para a pagina main, mas quando eu clico dentro do app e vou para uma outra tela, não sei como definir as cores para aquela activity especifica.

eu criei essa outra Activity2 e queria manipular ela assim como eu faço com a Main.

E quando eu criei essa nova, ela também não gerou os mesmos arquivos como um theme.xml especifico que é onde eu alteraria as cores.

[image: eu queria usar o theme para manipular activity2]

Meu codigo xmml theme esta assim:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.PrimeiroApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#B8370C</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#982706</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#595250</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:color">#000000</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, para realizar essa customização é necessário criar alguns temas, como tu já criou, agora o segundo passo é:

- No arquivo AndroidManifest.xml, procurar a activity em questão e alterar o tema dela, exemplo:

  ```
    <activity android:exported="true" android:theme="@style/seuTema">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  ```

A segunda tela deve estar parecida com isso também. Para customizar da forma que tu está querendo vai ser necessário adicionar o atributo **android:theme="@style/seuTema"**:

```
<activity android:exported="true" android:theme="@style/seuTema">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter> 
 </activity>
```

Comment: Evite cumprimentar e agradecer nas publicações. Nós não somo um engine de redes sociais. Nós somos um engine de Q&A sobre linguagens de programação, devemos focar mais no técnico.